# Generalized Notion of Group Equivariance

Tags: group-theory

One notion of group equivariance as applied to functions $f$ between sets $X,Y$ acted on by a group $G$ is: $f(gx)=gf(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and all $g\in G$.

Is there a way to generalize this to the case where we have a different group, $G'$, say, acting on $Y$? That is a way to make rigorous for all $x\in X, g\in G, h\in G'$ we have $f(gx)=hf(x)$? My hunch is that this could be made to work if $G$ is homomorphic (isomorphic?) to (a subgroup of) $G'$, but if this has already been done I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you explain your notation $G_x$? Usually it means the *stabilizer* of $x \in X$, i.e. $G_x = \{ g \in G \mid g \cdot x = x \}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack I edited it to hopefully clarify